# Thinking on $1-$forms as functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $\mathrm{T}M$ be its tangent bundle. I would like to think about $1-$forms as functions from $\mathrm{T}M\to \mathbb{R}$ and evaluate their differentiation. So, Let $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)  \to  \mathrm{T}M $ be a curve then what is 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}|_{t=0}\beta(\gamma(t)),$$
for a $1-$form $\beta$ on $M$? Is there any global form for this?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to think about $1-$forms as functions from
>   $\mathrm{T}M\to \mathbb{R}$

That is what a $1$-form is.

If you have a coordinate system, through which the $1$-form is locally written as $$f_1\operatorname{d}\!x_1+\ldots+f_n\operatorname{d}\!x_n$$
where the $f_i$ are functions of $x_1,\ldots, x_n$, then this means that $\beta$ is represented by the vector $(f_1,\ldots, f_n)$ at the given point (here $\gamma(0)$). Hence
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t}|_{t=0}\beta(\gamma(t))$$

is the inner product of the vectors $(f_1,\ldots, f_n)$ and $\gamma'(0)$.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, is there a global formula?

Comment: @Baghban I don't know what you mean by global formula. You can integrate a $1$-form on a $path$, but not on the whole manifold at once.